# Writing multiple scores onto the data file over several initiations

Tags: java, eclipse

I am making a very simple word mole game, but this high score writing issue is killing me. So the following method will show you what happens when u press restart after the game ends.

```
private static void HighScoreInput() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException
{

    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(dataFile);
    ObjectOutputStream saveItem = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);  
    player[intplayernum] = new HighScore(userName, timePlayed, totalwords, timecount.getText());

    saveItem.writeObject(player[intplayernum].toString());
    System.out.println(player[intplayernum].toString());


    System.out.println("Player score written to file.");
    saveItem.close();
     GameFrame.setVisible(false);
     GameFrame.dispose();
     askNameApp();
     intplayernum++;
}
```

But every time this happens, or when the user restarts, its supposed to ADD ON to the previous data, so we have a high score file with multiple scores. Instead, this only keeps the lAST INPUTTED PLAYER OBJECT on the file. I need to know how to keep adding on instead of replacing the names.

Comment: When you save the score, you create a new file and write just that score to the file.  Since you don't write anything else, that's all that will be in the file.  If you want to keep the previous contents, either use FileWriter with the append option, or keep using FileOutputStream, but write the previous contents of the file before writing the latest score.

Comment: Thanks Chris. I am kinda undersatnding what you mean, but can you please show me the code for how to do it

Comment: See my answer for the code you need to modify

Answer (score 0):

Actually, now that I look at the doc, try this line:

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(dataFile, true);
```

instead of this line:

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(dataFile);
```

The second value, true, tells the system to append instead of replace.

Comment: Chris, that was extremely good. It totally works now. But there's a little more problem left. Instead of adding the next player's name on the next line, it adds it right beside it. This is an issue, because when I want to read the file directly off of the actual file instead of an array, I would have to perform some complex code to make it work. Any way to get around that?

Comment: To give you a visual of how it looks, check this out...
¬í ¬í t NName: Jarraf Date: 2015/05/17_ 17: 53: 57 Total Words: 0 Time elapsed: 3.0 sec¬í t MName: Money Date: 2015/05/17_ 17: 54: 10 Total Words: 0 Time elapsed: 2.0 sec

All that^ is just one line, but its the info for 2 players